# Is there somewhere i can run manage.py command line in VS2019?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2019, django-manage.py

I'm looking to run manage.py command line to load data from my model with something like

> python manage.py loaddata mytest

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to be more familiar with the new version. But i'm unable to run manage.py command line. Does someone experieced with how i can manage my django environment on Visual Studio 2019? 
I can use 'normal' fonction on Python option like Make migration, migration, etc.. But i'm lost on how i can use other manage.py function.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you attempt to do it?

Comment: no error, everything work good! except i don't know how to run manage.py like loaddata or any other manage.py command line supported. Does VS2019 have a Python Shell that can run something like python manage.py runserver by command line?

Comment: All you need is a console window where you can run python

Comment: I've tryed with the Django console and normal console, but i always get error like if the virtual env isn't activate on the console!